# Javascript - render only updated html

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a class called render. That gets continually updated, and I would like to not update the whole class each time.

I have a string

```
var html1 = "<h1>Header</h1><p>this is a small paragraph</p><ul><li>list element 1.</li><li>list element 2.</li><li>list element 3.</li></ul>"
```

and `$('.render').html(html1)` produces:

```
<div class="render">
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <p>this is a small paragraph</p>
    <ul>
        <li>list element 1.</li>
        <li>list element 2.</li>
        <li>list element 3.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Lets say that I get a new html string which is just an update of `html1`

```
var html2 = 
"<h1>Header</h1>
<p>this is a small paragraph</p>
<ul>
<li>list element 1.</li>
<li>list element 2.</li>
<li>list element 3. With a small update.</li>
</ul>"
// newlines thrown in for clarity.
```

Is there a good way for me to insert the new html without re-rendering the whole thing.

Here is my project to try solve this issue [github/rontgen.js](http://github.com/eoinmurray/rontgen)

Comment: `Node.appendChild` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild

Comment: Not really (unless you want to write your own `diff` that patches only the elements that change).

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "a good way".  You can certainly write some code to do it, but it's probably not a simple task.

Comment: You could use jQuery to loop trough all child elements and check if there are any changes and if there are changes to a child then only replace the contents of that child.

Comment: If your concern is performance, I can ensure you that you aren't allowed to worry about that unless you optimize, concatenate and minify all your javascript and css files ;)

Comment: You can find the changed element and replace it (`replaceChild`).

Comment: Given the raison detre of your project: *"Most ... re-render the entire document every time the document changes"* and *"The point of this project is to find an elegant way to solve this, by re-rendering only the updated parts of the document."* Perhaps the more specific question should be "Is there a *fast* way for me to insert the new html". On small-to-medium changes, if you could find a way to "diff" the HTML and update faster than updating the entire doc, then you've got a performance benefit, otherwise? nope.

Comment: Almost, my goal is to insert and not re-render, not just a raw performance increase. I would like to insert mathjax later, so not re-rendering is more important that finding the fastest way to update the markdown.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work (syntax may be off but this should give you an idea of how to do it)

```
$('.render').children().each(function() {
   if ($(this).is('h1') && $(this).html() != html2.find('h1').html()) {
       $(this).html(html2.find('h1').html());
   }

 else if ($(this).is('p') && $(this).html() != html2.find('p').html()) {
      $(this).html(html2.find('p').html());
 }

 else if ($(this).is('ul') && $(this).html() != html2.find('ul').html()) {
     for (i=0; i<$(this).children('li').length; i++) {
        if ($(this).children('li')[i] != html2.find('ul').children('li')[i]) {
            $(this).children('li')[i].html(html2.find('ul').children('li')[i].html());
     }
   }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so a preliminary solution of mine is as follows, its like @dave's above, but I dont traverse the dom.

```
$(function(){

    // Cache the jQuery selectors
    var $editor = $("#editor");
    var $render = $('.render');

    $editor.focus();
    var firstTime = true;
    var cache = [''];

    var i = 0;
    var row_num = 1000;
    for(i = 0; i < row_num; i++){
        $render.append('<div id="node'+i+'"></div>')
    }

    $editor.keyup(function(){
        var fresh = $editor.val().split('\n\n');

        var i = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < fresh.length; i++){
            console.log(fresh[i]!==cache[i])
            if(fresh[i]!==cache[i]){
                $('#node'+i).html(marked(fresh[i]))
                renderMathJax('node'+i)
            }
        }
        var j;
        for(j = fresh.length; j < row_num; j++){
            $('#node'+j).empty()
        }

        cache = fresh;

    });

});


var renderMathJax = function (el) {
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub,el]);
}
```

Its performance is good because it only inserts and doesn't re-render, but still a few oddities if I delete more than one line at a time.